# Simple question about Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have this very simple example:

[image]

This generates these straightforward classes:

[image]

However, when I access the property Cities of any of my User objects read from the database it is always set to null. I thought that the Entity Framework would fill that property. Am I right? What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT: Just as a note I'm using 3.5, not 4 (looks like there are some key differences)

Comment: [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, EF uses [Lazy Loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx), in order to avoid mapping a whole referential integrity graph (imagine you've had more tables under `Cities` table - it would then make the underlying SQL query extremely huge and contain a lot of JOINs).

So you need to explicitly include subentities you want to be included and then a JOIN would occur behind the scenes. Call `.Include("Cities")` after you query for Users (or whatever queried subset of it like `Users.Where(...)`).

Comment: In the OP's case, lazy loading is probably *not* enabled, or the navigation property wouldn't have returned null...

Comment: When I use the Include it works. How can I turn off the Lazy Loading thing?

Comment: context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the Include method

```
context.Users.Include("Cities")
```

Comment: But if he didn't turn Lazy Loading off, it should populate it when he tries to access it. Include is only necessary if you're closing a connection or something and it can't lazy load (or you turn it off).

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting that you are getting null and not a list with 0 entries.

I therefore think that it is a problem with the model definition rather than a lazy loading or an include problem.

Try generating a new model.